# Perform the same operation on a bunch of controls from my storyboard without duplicate code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have 3 control types on a storyboard (bigButton0....bigButton11, btnSmall0...btnSmall11 and lbl0...lbl11).

I want to assign the same image to all btnBig0 to btnBig11.
I am currently using a long redundant code to do so because I didn't find any smarter solution, but I need to do this at runtime.

Can somebody tell me how to shorten my code?
Thank you very much.

```
NSString * sImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%.0f_%.0f_normal.png", L_CELL_W, L_CELL_H];

[bigButton0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton9 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton10 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bigButton11 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

sImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%.0f_%.0f_down.png", L_CELL_W, L_CELL_H];

[bigButton0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton9 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton10 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[bigButton11 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:sImageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to shorten this code.  One is to use an `IBOutletCollection`.  Give your view controller an instance variable that is a collection type like `NSArray`, and annotate it as an `IBOutletCollection` of `UIButton`:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *bigButtons;
}
...
```

If you prefer, you can make it a property, either in your public interface or in a class extension in your `.m` file:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

// Class extension at the top of MyViewController.m
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *bigButtons;
@end

// Normal class @implementation comes after the class extension
@implementation MyViewController
...
```

Now, in Interface Builder, you can connect this outlet collection to all of your big buttons.  Then you can iterate over the collection in your code:

```
NSString * sImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%.0f_%.0f_normal.png", L_CELL_W, L_CELL_H];
UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:sImageName];
sImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_bg_%.0f_%.0f_down.png", L_CELL_W, L_CELL_H];
UIImage *highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:sImageName];

for (UIButton *button in bigButtons) {
    [button setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Repeat (with a separate collection ivar) for each type of button.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me where exactly I would have to state IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *bigButtons; ?

Comment: I have added examples to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I need to ask again... When I add IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *bigButtons to the ViewController.m, Xcode is telling me "iboutletcollection attribute can only be applied to instance variables or properties. And when I tried to hook a button to this code line using "Referencing Outlet Collections" and then drawing a line to the code, it would not accept it.

Comment: It sounds like you put `IBOutletCollection` on a local variable instead of an instance variable or property.  Edit your question and paste in your new code.  Or look at some other examples of `IBOutletCollection`: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/2012/08/iboutletcollection-example-with.html or search stackoverflow for `IBOutletCollection`